# trouble implementing eql and equals in clisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

So I have my sample code down below:

```
(defvar answer 0)
(defvar response "")
(defun question ()
    (write-line "Enter your question")
    (setq response (read-line))
    (if (eql (subseq response 0 2) 'Is)
        (print "T")
        (print "nil")
))
```

The basic premise is to identify if the question asked begins with the word is.
The line that I think is giving me problems is (if (eql (subseq response 0 2) 'Is). I have other programs that use eql, but for some reason this use is always returning false no matter the input. I have already spent 3 hours trying a few different variations of this code, but none have worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since the title says "trouble implementing eql and equals" where are you implementing `eql` and `equals`?

Comment: eql is being used in this statement: `(if (eql (subseq response 0 2) 'Is)`. I had also tried using equals instead of eql in this statement. so eql is explicitly used and I included equals in the title to convey the fact I had already tried equals.

Comment: But you are not trying to **implement** either of them eg. `(defun equal (a b)...)`. You are trying to use them. Title is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is

```
(string-equal (subseq response 0 2) 'Is)
```

`string-equal` compares strings ignoring the character case. Unlike `string-equal` the `string=` function compares strings accounting for character case. An equivalent using `string=` function would be

```
(string= (string-upcase (subseq response 0 2)) 'Is)
```

Contrary to string comparison predicates the `eql` predicate compares lisp objects. For equal constant strings in compiled code it is likely to return **true** while in your case where one object is quoted literal and another object is computed character string it would fail.

For example `(eql 'is 'is)`  returns **true** while `(eql "is" "is")` is **false** in interpreted code.